# How do I push the installed kernel in a satellite server to other RHEL servers?

Tags: rhel, redhat-satellite

I have a satellite server that is running kernel 4.18.0-477.10.1.
But all my other RHEL 8 servers are running 4.18.0-372.32.1.

Am I missing something here, but shouldn't my satellite server be able to push out the 477 kernel if it has it installed?  Or am I supposed to run some command to allow it?  I've never ran a satellite server before.